# How to store a list of files; do a test; act on the list in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do what has to be a pretty common workflow:

1. Use `find` to build a list of files that I want to act on
2. Make a test of that list (e.g. that it's not empty)
3. Send that list to a command

How can I do this?

```
FILES=$(find $DIR -type f)
[ -z "$FILES" ] && exit 1
cmd "$FILES"
```

The `cmd` command doesn't seem to understand that `"$FILES"` is a list of arguments for it.

Comment: Why not `find $DIR -type f -exec cmd '{}' \;`?  (note: see also `-execdir` instead of `-exec` and `+` instead of `\;` in [find(1) Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html))

Comment: Maybe that would work if I can make cmd into a function. However, the raw command I do would have catastrophic consequences if executed on the wrong input. Testing is critical.

Comment: `find` guarantees that only files that match your criteria (e.g. files `-type f` below `$DIR`) are sequentially passed (that is what `'{}'` represents - each individual filename) where `cmd` is called on each one at a time. That is what `find` is for (among other things)

Comment: Ok, so find will never run cmd on nothing.

Comment: Correct -- no files match, `cmd` is never called.

Comment: Good to know. So, bash provides no way of resuming a pipe from a list though?

Comment: First you'd need to create a list. `"$FILES"` is just a single string. Things get tricky because filenames can contain spaces, newlines, `*`, etc.

Comment: Well, you are using some particular terms of art there `"list"` is specially defined in bash, and resuming a pipe is a bit unclear -- but, a pipe simply ties the `stdout` of a prior command to `stdin` of the next. So if the prior command fails, the pipeline fails -- so in that sense there is no resuming.

Comment: My brain thinks in terms of R's pipe operator here (e.g. substitute `%>%` for `|` since the latter means 'or'): `1:10 %>% log -> x` and then `x %>% exp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to say something like:

```
declare -a FILES
ifs_bak="$IFS"    # backup IFS
IFS=$'\n'         # set IFS to "\n" to split the result of find on it
FILES=( $(find "$DIR" -type f) )
IFS="$ifs_bak"    # restore IFS
[[ "${#FILES[@]}" -eq 0 ]] && exit 1
cmd "${FILES[@]}"
```

`"$FILES"` in your code is nothing but a single concatenated string of filenames (with spaces in between) and `cmd` will not accept that as a list of arguments. It will be easy to imagine what happens if you say: `cmd "file1 file2 file3 .."`.
You need to use an array instead. Then you are invoking as: `cmd "file1" "file2" "file3" ..`.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidC.Rankin said in a comment, the simple way to do this is with the `find` command's `-exec` primitive. This version will run the command once for each file:

```
find "$DIR" -type f -exec cmd {} \;
```

And this will run the command for groups of files:

```
find "$DIR" -type f -exec cmd {} +
```

In either case, if there are no files it will not run `cmd`. The `+` version *might* run the command more than once, if there are so many files that the list exceeds the maximum argument list size.

If you want more control, you can store a list of files as an array:

```
files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  files+=("$file") 
done < <(find "$DIR" -type f -print0)
[[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]] && exit 1
cmd "${files[@]}"
```

Note that there's a lot of syntactic elements here -- brackets, braces, parentheses, quotes, etc -- that're absolutely required for this to work right. BTW, the `<( )` (process substitution) trick used to capture `find`'s output is a bash-only feature, and isn't available even in bash if it's run under the name `sh`. So use a bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and don't override it by running the script with the `sh` command.